# Percentile from dictionary list

Tags: python, percentile

I am having an issue with extracting values from a dictionary. I have created this dictionary from a CSV file. However, I got stuck when I tried to extract percentile value for each key in the dictionary. My dictionary looks like this:

```
dic = {'2008': [10,20, 56, 30, 57], '1950': [10.1,59.6, 56, 30.8, 99.6]}.
```

I'd like to have my output as:

> 1950,56.0
>   2008,30.0

What I tried so far is:

```
import numpy as np

dic ={}

pert ={'key':'value'}
for k in dic.keys():

    for items in dic[k]:
    p = np.percentile(items,95)
    pert[k] = p
```

Comment: In the example code you say `percentile(items,95)`, which hints that you want the 95th percentile, but in your example the output you asked for is the median of each list. What do you actually want this code to do? Can you explain why the answer should be what you say?

Comment: Hanno, the language is in python. David, you are right. there was inconsistency in the code. percentile 95 will be replaced with 50.

Answer (score 4):

This make a dictionary with 95th percentiles:

```
dic = {'2008': [10,20, 56, 30, 57], '1950': [10.1,59.6, 56, 30.8, 99.6]}
res = {k: np.percentile(v, 95) for k, v in dic.items()}
```

The content of `res`:

```
{1950': 91.599999999999994, '2008': 56.799999999999997}
```

Get the median with:

```
>>> {k: np.median(v) for k, v in dic.items()}
{'1950': 56.0, '2008': 30.0}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. Appreciate your time

Comment: You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.